# Randomly getting booted off of SSH despite sending keepalives

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox, putty

I’ve cooked up a Debian 7 virtual machine (with VirtualBox) in an attempt to play with setting up my own server and other such cool tricks. This is all on one computer.

I can SSH into the virtual machine via putty, but after a short (inconsistent duration, ~15 seconds to ~3 mins) period I get booted off the server with the good 'ol error.

> Server unexpectedly closed network connection.

Naturally, I just changed my putty settings so that I will send a keepalive every 25 seconds.

This didn’t work, and now I'm straight out of ideas as to what to do to stop this, and I don't know if my error is somewhere in `sshd_config` or my putty configurations or any host of other possible things. Spending a while on Google also hasn’t turned up anything.

Looking through my sshd logs, my putty error logs, and my sshd_config isn't showing anything out of the ordinary.

EDIT: Here is my putty error log:

```
2015-02-20 15:03:28     Looking up host "127.0.0.1"
2015-02-20 15:03:28     Connecting to 127.0.0.1 port 3022
2015-02-20 15:03:28     Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
2015-02-20 15:03:28     Using SSH protocol version 2
2015-02-20 15:03:28     We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.63
2015-02-20 15:03:28     Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
2015-02-20 15:03:28     Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
2015-02-20 15:03:28     Host key fingerprint is:
2015-02-20 15:03:28     ssh-rsa 2048 ------------------------------
2015-02-20 15:03:28     Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
2015-02-20 15:03:28     Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
2015-02-20 15:03:28     Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
2015-02-20 15:03:28     Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
2015-02-20 15:03:32     Sent password
2015-02-20 15:03:32     Access granted
2015-02-20 15:03:32     Opening session as main channel
2015-02-20 15:03:32     Opened main channel
2015-02-20 15:03:32     Allocated pty (ospeed 38400bps, ispeed 38400bps)
2015-02-20 15:03:32     Started a shell/command
2015-02-20 15:04:56     Server unexpectedly closed network connection
```

EDIT x3: Here are the relevant results of an example failed session after looking at /var/log/auth.log.

```
Feb 21 16:16:38 CGIT sshd[2559]: Accepted password for web from 10.0.2.2 port 60037 ssh2
Feb 21 16:16:38 CGIT sshd[2559]: pam_unix(sshd:session) session opened for user web by (uid=0)
```

EDIT x2:

I've reinstalled debian in a new VM instance (this time through a CD install instead of a netinstall) and yet I still get disconnected randomly. This happens when running the VM as admin, and disabling all antivirus.

Comment: Did you check SSH server log to see why it disconnects you? Did you check PuTTY event log?

Comment: Which type of keepalive are you using? (It's not the TCP one, but the SSH one you need.)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl /var/log/auth.log isn't showing anything that seems out of the ordinary, but I can't say I'm looking in all the right places for certain. I've got the timer set to 30 seconds on the "connection" tab of putty, and have enabled TCP keepalives. Is there anything more I need to do?

Comment: Since I can't edit after 5 minutes: @MartinPrikryl Also, the putty event log just says "Started a shell/command" then (1 minute, 16 seconds later) says "Server unexpectedly closed network connection" with no other diagnostic information.

Comment: @JakeGould Here is the putty event log: http://pastebin.com/aMd85F2j

Comment: The thing is, I've spent my fair time checking the logs, and to me, nothing seems out of the ordinary. I've gone through sshd_config, gone through my putty error logs, and gone through my sshd logs. Nothing is giving me anything to go off of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error was a problem with VirtualBox.

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=66067

If you have this error, you may upgrade to version 4.3.23 and your problems may be fixed.